# How to group by row in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am new to SSRS Reporting.

I want to group items by "ChallanNumber", but I also want to show all details of that challan and it's child challan.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would create a table with your detail records showing all the records from all groups, then right click on the row selector (or click the drop down under Row Groups) and **Add Group-->Parent Group**. For the Group By, select your **challan** field and check the Add Group Header box to add the extra line for the group.

The group will be created but with a new left column that you may not want. You can delete the new column. Add the fields you want to your new group header line.